# Possible to use Spring 4 with Tiles 2 ?

Tags: tiles, spring-4

Is it possible to use spring 4 with tiles 2 ?

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to configure tiles with spring web, and many of the classes have changed in tiles 3 vs tiles 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically follow [the section about Tiles 3 in Spring's reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles) - and just change package names `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3` into `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2`.

Note that [Tiles 2 support in Spring has been deprecated as of Spring 4.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#migrating-to-spring-framework-42)